# Twitter Integration using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Ruby on Rails application (Ruby-1.9, Rails-3.2)which integrates with twitter to display the latest tweets containing a particular "keyword" dynamically. But it throws an ***error*** as  **NameError in TweetsController#create uninitialized constant Twitter::Search** on the browser .
I have run the db migrations, restarted the server and tried for various options available on the net. But nothing seems to work. Can anyone help to resolve this error ?

The model and controller files are below

**Tweet.rb (model file)**

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base



def self.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets(keyword)


search = Twitter::Search.new


search.containing(keyword).result_type("recent").per_page(100).fetch.each do |tweet_results|

  twitter_created_at = DateTime.parse(tweet_results.created_at)

  unless Tweet.exists?(['twitter_created_at = ? AND from_user_id_str = ?', DateTime.parse(tweet_results.created_at), tweet_results.from_user_id_str])


    Tweet.create!({

        :from_user => tweet_results.from_user,

        :from_user_id_str => tweet_results.from_user_id_str,

        :profile_image_url => tweet_results.profile_image_url,

        :text => tweet_results.text,

        :twitter_created_at => twitter_created_at

       })

    end

  end

 end

end
```

**TweetsController**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

def index
end 

def create

  String strText = params[:tweet][:search].to_s

  Tweet.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets(strText)


 if Tweet.count > 0                         

   Tweet.delete_all        

end    

    Tweet.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets(strText)

    @tweets = Tweet.order("twitter_created_at desc")  
    render 'index'  

  end

end
```

**Index.html.erb (The view file)**

```
<h1>Twitter connect</h1>



<form action="create" method="post">

  <label for="keyword">Enter Keyword</label>

    <input id="keyword" name="tweet[search]" size="30" type="text" />


  <input type="submit" value="search" />

  </br> <br>  

 </form>

</br></br>  



<div id="container">

   <% if (@tweets != nil && @tweets.count>0) then %>

<ul>

      <% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>

     <li class="<%=cycle('odd', '')%>">

    <%= link_to tweet.from_user, "http://twitter.com/#{tweet.from_user}", :class => "username", :target => "_blank" %>  

    <div class="tweet_text_area">

        <div class="tweet_text">

            <%=raw display_content_with_links(tweet.text) %>

        </div>

        <div class="tweet_created_at">

            <%= time_ago_in_words tweet.twitter_created_at %> ago

        </div>

     </div>

   </li>

    <% end %>

   </ul>

 <% end %>

</div>
```

The gemfile is as below

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6',:group => :development 


#gem 'ruby-mysql'
#gem 'mysql2'
group :production do
gem 'pg'
 end

 gem 'twitter', '4.6.2'
```

Comment: what is the gem you used for twitter ? The above error is because you have not included the gem library in your app. can you list out the gem or past your gem file.

Comment: The gemfile is pasted in the latest edit. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Include below code in your **application.rb** ***or*** top of **app/models/tweet.rb** files

```
require 'twitter'
```

Ex:-

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'twitter'
  ....
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried that workaround. But still gives the same error. Any other way out ?